# Problemas Con Módulos Python

Tags: python, poo, python-import, modulos, module.exports

yo tengo un problema "sencillo" pero probe con todo y no me funciona. Resulta que estoy haciendo una calculadora, y tengo dos archivos en distintas carpetas, un main.py y un modulo con las operaciones y las funciones. Todos estos archivos estan ordenandos de la siguiente forma:

> Python Fundamentos:

- MateMath(Dentro de esta carpeta tengo las otras dos carpetas con los archivos correspondientes):

> Main

- main.py

> Modulos

- operaciones_basicas.py

Es decir la carpeta principal seria python fundamentos, de esa carpeta tengo otra que se llama matemath en la que tengo dos carpetas una que es el main, donde dentro de esa carpeta se encuentra el main.py, y otra que es modulos donde voy a poner todos los modulos de las funciones que necesite ir agregando a la calculadora. Pero me salta error con el import y he provado de todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe todo tipos de import pero aun asi sigo sin poder importar el modulo ayuda porfavor

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 -> De preferencia copia y pega código en lugar de imágenes que tienen código. Saludos

Comment: Usa los puntos para navegar por carpetas relativas. `from ..Modulos import operaciones_basicas` Y lee https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: Yo estoy aprendiendo también, y estoy teniendo un problema también al importar módulos, pero diría que en tu caso el posible problema es que no tienes creado el archivo __init__.py dentro de la carpeta del módulo, este es necesario para que se puedan importar.